# Why wont this simple code work all of a sudden?

Tags: php

Why won't this print "success" when I submit the form? I'm pretty sure it should.

```
<?php
    if (count($_POST) > 0) {
        echo "success!!";
    }
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please ask a more informative question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At a guess, the submit field has no name, so it won't be included in `$_POST`. Your file upload will be placed in `$_FILES`, see [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Answer (score 3):

It is also good practice to NOT ommit the `action` attribute.

If you want the form to submit to itself, try

```
<form method="post" action="?" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

*or*

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

[Further reading on second method](http://www.alexanderdickson.com/blog/2010/03/form-security-submitting-forms-to-themselves-in-php/) **Disclaimer**: Link to my own blog

Comment: Why is that a disclaimer? You're not sure about the contents of your blog?

Comment: Just to let people know that the link is to my own blog so I'm biased by linking to it :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (count($_POST['submit']) > 0) {
        echo "success!!";
    }
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: How about `if ($_POST['submit'] == 'upload')`

Comment: I normally just have if ($_POST['submit']) {